# Converting Linux Curl Command to PHP

Tags: php, linux, curl

I want to know, how to convert linux curl command to PHP. This is my linux curl command. Thanks in advance.

```
curl -i -F api_password=<YOUR_API_PASSWORD> -F file=@<LOCAL_FILE_PATH> https://upload.wistia.com/
```

Comment: Did you tried something, anything ?

Comment: don't waste your time , that we write php code for you , start from http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php , then try your self , if any problem , tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the starting point that you can use...

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $THE_REMOTE_URL_YOU_ARE_POSTING_TO);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    "file" => "@c:\\file_location.txt", // note the double \\ when used within double quotes
    'api_password' => 12345
  )); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```